# Django FileField in model, S3 Storage + Boto, 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto

I'm developing a web application in Django, and one of its features is adding new articles with a photo.

My `Article` model class contains `models.FileField`. I use `S3BotoStorage` as `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` (Amazon S3).

Users can add a photo to an article in two ways:
1) Upload a photo from disk (by using `input type=file`)
2) Paste URL to existing photo online

If users uses option 1), everything works. I get uploaded file in view from `request.FILES` dictionary and assing it to `FileField` in `Article` object. The photo is uploaded to S3.

But when user pastes URL to a photo, the first thing I have to do in view is to download this photo. I do it by using function:

```
def downloadPhotoFromURL(url):
try:
    img = urllib.urlretrieve(url)[0]
    return img
except Exception:
    return None
```

Then I save this image to `FileField` in model, so my whole code responsible for downloading image, and uploading it to S3 is like this:

```
articleImg = downloadPhotoFromURL(url)
f = File(open(articleImg), 'rb')
newArticle.image.save('tmp', f)
```

In this situation, I cannot upload it to S3 and after 2 minutes I'm receiving `BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request`. Unfortunately I don't have any other information why this request is bad. Any idea what can be going wrong? By the time I saved an image to model, I had saved a model, so model exists when I try to upload photo to S3.

Comment: Did you fix this problem?